# How to stop receipient's signature being removed when replying to email in Thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird

When I hit reply to an email, the recipient's signature i removed if it is preceded by "--". Is there a way to stop this in Thunderbird? Many thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This behavior is actually by design.  The "-- " (dash-dash-space line) is the "signature cut line" and is placed by conforming mail clients (e.g., Thunderbird, Gmail, etc.) for precisely the reason that they can be trimmed automatically from responses.

Some background: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signature_block

I believe they originally came out of Usenet circles, and the idea was that if someone had posted to a list, the signature was already recorded and seen by subscribers.  Since bandwidth was at a premium (is still, worldwide), cutting it would not needlessly waste time, space, and money.

As far as actively including it when replying, I don't know of a way.  Either trawl the Thunderbird extensions, or hire someone to build one for you.

Comment: Many thnks for your response. I was aware of the purpose of the -- issue, but I think it is a bit rude to respond to some people who are not aware of this issue and they might think "why has this guy removed my signature (and added his own), has he not got better things to do than waste time editing my original email etc". Maybe I am being paranoid...

Comment: @user141158: I suppose it depends on who you ask.  In this day and age, I would think that the person would either not know what's up but ignore it (especially if they reply and their mail client does the same thing), or wouldn't even notice.  And frankly, I suspect the latter, unless they ask.

Answer (score 4):

Thunderbird has a hidden option to do this. Go to Tools -> Options -> Advanced -> General -> Config Editor…
Filter on mail.strip_sig_on_reply and toggle the preference to false.